# How can I disable Alloy UI CSS in a Liferay Custom Theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, liferay

I want to develop a Liferay Custom Theme. So I need to disable the Alloy UI only CSS and Bootstrap CSS. Other functionality like the drag and drop protlet and calender events need to remain the same.

The only thing I need to do is disable the Alloy UI css in the theme level. How can we achieve that? In which page do I need to edit/remove the css of Alloy?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 levels from which you can base your theme. Each layer builds on top of the next.

- `_unstyled` - Has all the rule sets, but no rules.
- `_styled` - Only structural CSS is copied into your theme.
- `Classic` - All CSS is copied from the default Liferay theme.

To use something other than classic add a property named "theme.parent" whose value is one of the above. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>

<project name="sample-styled-minimal-theme" basedir="." default="deploy">
    <property name="plugin.version" value="1" />
    <property name="theme.parent" value="_styled" />

    <import file="../build-common-theme.xml" />
</project>
```